# Mockito self-invoking doAnswer calls repeatedly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, integration-testing

I'm using mockito to return different values for the same function calls:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
  int counter = 0;

  @Override
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    if (counter == 0) {
        counter += 1;
      return object1;
    } else {
      return object2;
    }
  }
}).when(thing).thingFunction();
```

`thingFunction` is only called once for right now, however, on that first call, mockito starts self-invoking over and over (3-5 times) thus increasing this counter. No idea why this would be happening. Is this correct?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've shown here.  Is it possible that the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be correct except there is a warning in your statement because Answer is a generic class. You should write `new Answer<Object>() { //.. }` (according to the returning type of your mocked method)

I wrote a Junit Test with Mockito 1.10.19 for clarification:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass {


    Object object1 = new Object();
    Object object2 = new Object();

    class Thing{
        public Object thingFunction(){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        Thing thing = Mockito.mock(Thing.class);
        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
              int counter = 0;

              @Override
              public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    counter += 1;
                  return object1;
                } else {
                  return object2;
                }
              }
            }).when(thing).thingFunction();

        assertEquals(object1, thing.thingFunction());
        assertEquals(object2, thing.thingFunction());
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out the underlying framework was unknowingly executing function calls on my mock.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an `Answer` with a self made counter you could also achieve the same behaviour chaining `thenReturn`.
E.g.

```
when(thing.thingFunction()).thenReturn(object1).thenReturn(object2);
```

For all subsequent calls object2 will be returned.